# Java generics type deduction error

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I've come across error with what I thought would have been a straight forward deduction where a method using generics specifies a version of a generic class as one parameter and for a second parameter it specifies something of the type used for the version of the previous parameter.

```
static class GenericClass<T0>
{
    T0 getT()
    {
        return null;
    }

    static <T1> void func3( GenericClass<T1> a, T1 b )
    {

    }
}

void testcase( GenericClass<? extends Integer> a )
{
    GenericClass.func3( a, a.getT() );
}
```

Unfortunately it shows as an error:

```
"The method func3(GenericClass<T1>, T1) in the type GenericClass is not applicable for the arguments (GenericClass<capture#6-of ? extends Integer>, capture#7-of ? extends Integer)"
```

However this change to the header of func3 works.

```
static <T1> void func3( GenericClass<? extends T1> a, T1 b )
```

and so does this change to the header of the testcase method.

```
void testcase( GenericClass<Integer> a )
```

Even if the testcase header doesn't give a concrete type for the class, the class specifies the return type will be the same as its generic type so why does the error message suggest they are potentially two different types?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java never keeps track of whether two `?` types are the same `?`, even if it could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example isn't obvious because `Integer` is `final`, so let's take an example where `Parent` has two subclasses, `Foo` and `Bar`.

`? extends Parent` means some specific subtype of `Parent`. So `GenericClass<Foo>` and `GenericClass<Bar>` could be used where a `GenericClass<? extends Parent>` is expected.

Here

```
static <T1> void func3( GenericClass<T1> a, T1 b )
```

you have a generic method where the generic type parameter is used in both parameter declarations. The compiler must guarantee that the type is correct in both provided arguments during a method invocation.

Given this

```
GenericClass<? extends Parent> a = ...;
GenericClass.func3( a, a.getT() );
```

it has no way to do that. You must first understand that Java doesn't know that both those arguments come from the same source. All it looks at is their types.

The first argument is of type `GenericClass<? extends Parent>` while the second argument is of type `? extends Parent`. Consider the following

```
GenericClass<? extends Parent> a = new GenericClass<Foo>(someFoo);
GenericClass<? extends Parent> b = new GenericClass<Bar>(someBar);
GenericClass.func3( a, b.get());
```

The two arguments have the exact same compile time type as the method call above, but it is easier to see why it would fail. It cannot guarantee that `T` will be bound to the same type for both arguments. It must therefore fail.

Comment: Ah yes it makes sense now - "Java doesn't know that both those arguments come from the same source". So the second parameter's type is simply derived independently from the get-method and then it compares the parameters against each other. Thanks.